# Finding the nth number of primes

Tags: python, math, computer-science, primes

I can not figure out why this won't work. Please help me

```
from math import sqrt

pN = 0 
numPrimes = 0
num = 1

def checkPrime(x):
   '''Check\'s whether a number is a prime or not'''
   prime = True
   if(x==2):
      prime = True
   elif(x%2==0):
      prime=False
   else:
      root=int(sqrt(x))
      for i in range(3,root,2):
         if(x%i==0):
            prime=False
            break
   return prime

n = int(input("Find n number of primes. N being:"))

while( numPrimes != n ):
   if(  checkPrime( num ) == True ):
      numPrimes += 1
      pN = num
      print("{0}: {1}".format(numPrimes,pN))
   num += 1

print("Prime {0} is: {1}".format(n,pN))
```

Comment: What do you think the program has to do? And what it does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change

```
root=int(sqrt(x))
```

into

```
root=int(sqrt(x))+1
```

(Take 9 for instance, `int(sqrt(9))` is `3`, and `range(3, 3, 2)` is `[]`, and you *do* really want to test dividing by `3`!).

Technically, 1 is not a prime either. Add

```
if(x<=1):
   prime = False
```

and you'll get the same result as http://www.rsok.com/~jrm/first100primes.html

Comment: Nice answer. Just modify the condition to be: if(x<=1)

Answer (score 1):

Differently from what @Braxton says in a comment, the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm can easily be adapted to generate unbounded primes (e.g. as a potentially-infinite generator, which can then be curtailed as desired e.g. by `itertools.slict`).

See [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119-sieve-of-eratosthenes/) for an unbounded Sieve in Python (and be sure to apply the enhancements shown in the comments, including mine;-) or see the same recipe as finally edited for the printed Cookbook [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Q0s6Vgb98CQC&lpg=PT703&dq=python%20cookbook%20sieve&pg=PT703#v=onepage&q&f=false) (unfortunately the discussion part is curtailed in this google books hit, but at least the Solution's code is all there;-).

Comment: Thank you! I obviously have a lot to learn, but that was tremendously helpful