# Finding the nth Prime

Tags: python, primes

I am trying to create an algorithm which will output the nth prime number. I have written up the code but whenever I run it I am given the 980th prime, when it should output the 1000th prime?

```
testNumber = 1
countPrimes = 0
testCounter = 2
isPrime = False
currentPrime = 0

while(countPrimes <= 1021): #runs for the first 1k primes
    testCounter=2
    isPrime = True
    if(testNumber%2 != 0): #checks if test number is odd
        while(testCounter*testCounter < testNumber): #counter^2 needs to be less than testNumber
            if(testNumber%testCounter == 0):
                isPrime = False
            testCounter = testCounter + 1
        if(isPrime==True):
            countPrimes = countPrimes + 1
            currentPrime = testNumber
    testNumber+=1

print currentPrime
```

Comment: The logic is completely broken.  Do you do anything at all to `testNumber`?  Write the logic on a paper before coding it.

Comment: @devnull Thanks for pointing out I didn't do anything to testNumber, I just had to increment it, so I don't think the logic is broken. But for some reason it is now giving me the prime before the one I am looking for?

Comment: When I run your code, it prints 7919, which is the 1000th prime.  What is the problem here?

Comment: @Brionius Sorry I should have pointed out. In order to get that result  the while loop needs to have countPrimes<=1021, not <=1000 as it should be.

Comment: I understand.  See my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the nth number of primes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030226/finding-the-nth-number-of-primes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is also counting odd perfect squares (9, 25, 49, etc) as prime numbers.  That is because your code stops testing for divisibility just before you get to the square root of the number.  To exclude perfect squares, you need to check one more integer:

I.e. instead of:

```
while(testCounter*testCounter < testNumber): #counter^2 needs to be less than testNumber
```

try this:

```
while(testCounter*testCounter < testNumber + 1): #counter^2 needs to be less than testNumber
```

Additionally, you'll still be one off because your code counts 0 and 1 as prime, and doesn't count 2.

Comment: that's usually written `testCounter*testCounter <= testNumber`.